# 'jQuery' not defined after intalling jQuery in Nuget manager

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a task of upgrading versions of Bootstrap and jQuery on our ASP.NET. The current version is Bootstrap 3. The problem is that after downloading Bootstrap 4.1.3 from Nuget it also upgraded jQuery from 2.2.1 to 3.0.0.

And now almost all plugins that we use, such as jQuery UI and smartmenus report that 'jQuery is not defined'

[image]

If I revert the jQuery back to 2.1.1, it works.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, kind of an unfortunate overlook. Had to update manually the new jQuery version in BundleConfig.cs in map App_Start:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js", /// <---UPDATED THIS TO 3.0.0
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js",
```